# When using Redux-Form I don't understand why the value of my input is always returned as a string. I want two fields to be numbers only

Tags: react-redux, redux-form

I want to validate that two of my fields called **price** and **quantity** are receiving an input value with a type of number before I submit the form, so in my validate function I write the following code:

```
function validate(values) {
    const errors = {};

    _.map(FIELDS, (config, field) => {
        if (!values[field]) {
            errors[field] = `Please Enter ${config.label}`;
        }
        if (typeof values['price'] !== 'number') {
            errors['price'] = 'Please enter a number';
        }
        if (typeof values['quantity'] !== 'number') {
            errors['quantity'] = 'Please enter a number';
        }
    });

    return errors;
}
```

The error 'Please enter a number' is shown on my form regardless of whether I enter a number or not, so I console logged the typeof input value for price and quantity and it turns out they are always strings. How should I validate the form so that I can check to see if price and quantity receive a number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data will always come to you from input fields as strings. Instead you could use a regex to see that it only containers numbers instead of doing

`typeof values['quantity'] !== 'number'`

You should try something like this

`const reg = /^\d+$/;`

This will match numbers for you only. Match against this regex and determine if you have numbers or not.

If you want to match signed and float numbers without empty strings, use this regex:

`/^-?\d+\.?\d*$/`

Here's how you would use it:

```
const numberRegex = /^-?\d+\.?\d*$/;

if (!/^\d*$/.test(value)) {
    errors['price'] = 'Please enter a number';
}
...
```

Comment: How do you use the regex to make sure the input is only numbers? I see what you mean as to why I should use it, but I don't really know how.

Comment: @Mjuice I have updated my answer with a sample usage.